# Opportunity Split Amount not updating

Tags: opportunity-split

Anyone experience an issue where Opportunity Split Amount is not updating?  My users are creating new opportunities, then creating quotes, which syncs products back to the opportunity (the Opportunity Amount field shows properly) but the Opportunity Split Amount does not register a change (stays $0).  If I go in and modify the split % from 100 to 99 then back to 100 again, it registers and correctly shows the opportunity amount, but this seems like a bug...